# C++ Class and Object Variables Seem To Be Overwritten When Accessed Elsewhere

Tags: c++

this is for a CS project I'm working. After designing my classes I've come across a problem where certain variables are being overwritten when being called again. In a specific case, I'm trying to make a int type = 1 when constructed, but later when I recall that variables outside the function, it gets changed to 6422216. I'm fairly certain that it's with my bad use of pointers and addresses, but I'm not sure how to find it.

There was a similar problem earlier with the time variable but I managed to fix it using Event* newEvent = new Event(event constructor parameters), though I'm not sure why that fixed it.

Main Function Starter Point:

```
GEL EventList = GEL(); // Where GEL is a class type that contains an event list
int main()
{
    //VarInit intializes all of the main variables
    VarInit();
    
    //REMEMBER: 0 = ARRIVAL TYPE, 1 = DEPARTURE TYPE
    //Class functions goes as such
    //EventList.Schedule(float Time, int Type, Packet NewPacket) where Packet is a separate packet class
    EventList.Schedule(GenArrivalTime(), 0, GenPacket());

    for(int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
    {
        //Example Gen Arrival Time
        
        Event CurrentEvent = Event(EventList.Remove());

        cout << "Current Event addr: " << &CurrentEvent << "\n";
        float CurrentTime = CurrentEvent.EventTime;
        cout << "CurrentEvent Time: " << CurrentTime << "\n";
        cout << "CurrentEvent Type: " << CurrentEvent.EventType << "\n";
        //Here the Type gets changed from 0 to 6422216
    }
```

Class Functions:

```
//I don't believe that there are any issues here
//When printing out the output it seems ok
void GEL::Schedule(float Time, int Type, Packet InsPacket)
{
    //create a new event called event with all of these arguments
    //Event(int _EventTime, Packet _ServicedPacket, int _EventType, Event* _NextEvent, Event * _PrevEvent);
    std::cout << "w/in GEL::Schedule EventTime = " << Time << "\n";
    std::cout << "w/in GEL::Schedule EventType = " << Type << "\n";
    //Type is OK here
    Event * NewEvent = new Event(Time, InsPacket, Type, NULL, NULL);
    //wow finally, all I had to do was insert the NEW keyword prolly because it doesn't change
    // insert that into the Insert function
    Insert(*NewEvent);
};

//I believe there might be an issue here, within the debugging print
//everything seems to be fine however afterwards it does change
Event GEL::Insert(Event NewEvent)
{
    if(FrontEventPtr == NULL)
    {
        //If there is nothing in the FrontEventPtr (head), then have the FrontEventPtr = NewEvent
        //Putting volatile as the packet seems to fix it here, but later breaks again in Remove()

        std::cout << "w/in GEL.Insert(): FrontEventPtr is NULL\n";

        //make the pointer point towards the new event
        FrontEventPtr = &NewEvent;

        std::cout << "w/in GEL::Insert() FrontEventPtr address: " << FrontEventPtr << "\n";
        std::cout << "w/in GEL.Insert(): FrontEventPtr -> EventTime = " << FrontEventPtr->EventTime << "\n";
        std::cout << "w/in GEL::Insert() EventType = " << FrontEventPtr->EventType << "\n";
        //hmmm for some reason EventType get's reassigned at this point

        return *FrontEventPtr;
    }

    //At this point FrontEventPtr contains something
    std::cout << "FrontEventPtr not null, setting a placeholder variable to store FrontEventPtr for further operations\n";
    Event* EventPlaceHolder = FrontEventPtr;

    if(EventPlaceHolder->EventTime > NewEvent.EventTime)
    {
        //If the current FrontEventPlaceholder is greater than the NewEvent Time, then set the new FrontEventPlaceholder equal to the NewEvent and swap items
        std::cout << "Swapping Items because old time is > new time\n";
        FrontEventPtr = &NewEvent;
        NewEvent.NextEvent = EventPlaceHolder;
        EventPlaceHolder->PrevEvent = &NewEvent;
        return NewEvent;
    }

    while((EventPlaceHolder->NextEvent != NULL) && (NewEvent.EventTime > EventPlaceHolder->NextEvent->EventTime))
    {
        //Keep swapping items until we find the right place to put the event
        EventPlaceHolder = EventPlaceHolder->NextEvent;
    }

    NewEvent.PrevEvent = EventPlaceHolder;
    NewEvent.NextEvent = EventPlaceHolder->NextEvent;
    EventPlaceHolder->NextEvent = &NewEvent;

    if(NewEvent.NextEvent != NULL)
    {
        NewEvent.NextEvent->PrevEvent = &NewEvent;
    }

    return NewEvent;
};

//The problem is very apparent here, it seems that the type variable changes here.
Event GEL::Remove()
{
    std::cout << "w/in GEL::Remove() FrontEventPtr address: " << FrontEventPtr << "\n";
    std::cout << "w/in GEL::Remove() FrontEventPtr -> EventTime = " << FrontEventPtr->EventTime << "\n";
    std::cout << "w/in GEL::Remove() EventType = " << FrontEventPtr->EventType << "\n";

    if(FrontEventPtr == NULL)
    {
        std::cout << "w/in GEL::Remove(), FrontEventPtr is null, returning *FrontEventPtr\n";
        return *FrontEventPtr;
    }

    std::cout << "w/in GEL::Remove(), FrontEventPtr != NULl\n";
    
    Event first_event = *FrontEventPtr;

    if(first_event.NextEvent != NULL)
    {
        first_event.NextEvent->PrevEvent = NULL;
    }

    FrontEventPtr = first_event.NextEvent;

    first_event.NextEvent = NULL;

    std::cout << "w/in GEL::Remove first_event.EventTime: " << first_event.EventTime << "\n";

    return first_event;
};
```

If you need anymore information let me know.
Also this is my first time posting on stackOverflow so i'm not aware of the etiquette when asking questions let me know if something was bad etiquette.
Thanks for taking time to help

Comment: If you're going to use pointers you need to be consistent. `Schedule` creates an object with `new` then you pass the object by value to `Insert` which makes a temporary copy, then you store the address of that temporary copy which is destroyed when the function ends. In `Remove` `Event first_event = *FrontEventPtr;` also makes a copy.

Answer (score 0):

In your Insert function, NewEvent is not a pointer but a value, that means when you call Insert(*Event);, it create a copy, after the Insert function return, the object NewEvent is destroyed.

I think you should change the Insert signature to Insert(Event* NewEvent)

Comment: Bless your soul, I spent so long trying to debug this. The only way I would've found out how to fix this would've been for me to randomly change things until something worked. Thanks!